# Algorithm to look for optima in huge discrete universe

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, combinations, mathematical-optimization

I am currently looking for algorithm that would return the optimal (or at least one of the best sub-optimal) combination of items given a size and a universe (in general between 10-15 among 50, so about a several million of billion possibilities...) and a scoring function which gives the performance of each combination in the past (the function to optimize takes between 2msec and 1sec to run depending of the complexity I choose).
The main problem for me is to handle the number of iterations to do if I have to test all the possible combinations (I cannot even store all the combination possibilities in a list of lists... and have to use generator to do so for each assessment if I do not want to run out of memory).
Unfortunately, for some functions I cannot use so-called "genetic" algorithm based on iterations (going from the best of 2, the best, of 3,.. basket of n and so on ... with some checks on the sub-baskets when adding a new item).
This type of algorithm is pretty fast and gives quite good result most of the time.

I already tried simulated annealing (scipy.basinhopping version or a custom version I coded) but it takes too much time for each iteration if I go beyond 15 among 25-30 since I cannot store all the combinations at the beginning of the algorithm and have to use a generator for each assessment. Moreover, sometimes I am not really satisfied by the optimum given.

If you have an idea, advice or hint, I would take everything. And if you want to see my simulated annealing function, do not hesitate to ask me.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Simulated annealing is applied to much bigger problems than this, I use a variant myself daily. How big is the code base you're currently using? Is it reasonable to post or is it in a repo somewhere you can link to?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that there is no single best solution to your question, but here are some suggestions:

- branch and bound (if you can design a good bound function)
- simulated annealing (try different cool down rates and neighbourhood size)
- anthill colony (usually less efficient than SA)
- metropolis (usually less efficient than SA)
- tabu search (does not give a lot of improvement but good even for hard problems)
- linear programming (if problem can be formulated in these terms)

It is also common to combine several techniques on a really hard problem. 
There is also a python library implementing many of these methods (and many others), [or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools). Unfortunately, it is not well documented

I don't think you need a full set of combinations for simulated annealing since it is a local search technique. In a typical scenario, you generate a new state (e.g. by adding random delta to a random parameter, or select a random point within radius in the problem space), then make a decision whether you're going to accept this change using probability formula. I.e. one of its advantages is exactly small memory footprint